# Question regarding a proof of the uncountability of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, real-numbers

I recently read theorem $2.14$ from baby Rudin. Here is what it states:

Let $A$ be the set of all sequences whose elements are the digits $0$
and $1$. This set $A$ is uncountable.

He goes on to prove this theorem and then continues with the following comment:

Readers who are familiar with the binary representation of the real
numbers (base 2 instead of 10) will notice that Theorem $2.14$ implies that the
set of all real numbers is uncountable. I read about the binary representation of the real numbers here on stack exchange but I'm wondering why this isn't implied with the decimal representation of the real numbers.

I construct a map $f$ which takes an element of $A$ and maps it to the number $1,s$. So if for example $s\in A $ is $01011010...$ then the number it corresponds to is $1,01011010...$

Then the set $f(A)$ is uncountable and since $f(A)\subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable as well. Is this also a valid proof or is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Surely you can see that you can make exactly the same arguments using decimal digits as you can using binary digits?

Comment: After reading about it I can. It just seemed weird to me that he mentioned the binary representation, making me think that maybe it isn't possible to prove the uncountability of the real numbers using the decimal representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each argument has an advantage, both can be made correct. A common mistake in Rudin's scenario is to identify each sequence with a binary number in $[0,1]$. This looks naively like a bijection (it is surjective) but it fails to be injective, because (for example) the following two sequences represent the same number:

$$ 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots \quad\text{vs}\quad 1,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots$$

As [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/65013) notes, there are only countably many exceptions which prevent this from being injective, and hence $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

Meanwhile, your argument is actually more direct - it is obviously injective. This is because in decimal, the ambiguity above is between (say) $0.9999\ldots$ and $1.000\ldots$, and your image only ever contains one of them. However, your function is very far from surjective, so it leaves open the possibility that there are many more decimal numbers than there are 0-1 sequences (and there are not).

Of course, in your example, starting with a 1 means that your image is a subset of $[1,2]$. But that hardly matters.

Comment: I did not claim that my function is surjective, but now that you mention it I don't see how it isn't. Still, isn't it enough that my function is injective? Even if I'm not considering every possible decimal number that is a sequence of $0-1$, $f(A)$ is still a subset of the reals, no?

Comment: It isn't surjective because, for example, it doesn't include the decimal number $1.2$. It is enough for your function to be injective (that's why I say it's more direct - you get to the point faster). The deficiency with not being surjective is unrelated to the main claim. It's where I say "it leaves open the possibility that there are many more ..."

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant it isn't surjective to the numbers of the form $1,01001011...$. Also, there is another point in your answer that confuses me. How do the sequences you mention correspond to the same number?

Comment: $1.0111111$ (infinite 1s) and $1.1000000$ (infinite 0s) are the same binary number, for the same reason that $0.9999$ (infinite 9s) and $1.00000$ (infinite 0s) are the same decimal number. See e.g [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) for an explanation.

Comment: I understand it now! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Good, glad I could help! If this answers your question, please mark it as an answer.